# Creating alias for Trash

Tags: linux, bash, bash-alias

I am a newbie. I set an alias in .bashrc file as follow.

```
alias myrm='mv /home/user/Trash/*'
```

The purpose is that when I use myrm comment, for example $myrm foo, the file "foo" has to be moved to the Trash folder which is in my home folder (/home/user/Trash).

Then I did

```
$source ~/.bashrc
```

After this, when I try to use myrm by typing $myrm foo, I get the following error message.

> mv: cannot stat ‘/home/user/Trash/*’: No such file or directory

How this problem can be solved?

Comment: Syntax is `mv SOURCE DESTINATION` and not `mv DESTINATION SOURCE`. See `man mv` and `help alias`. Use a function. See `help function`.

Comment: Investigate [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html#Positional-Parameters).  Your script wants a `$1` between the mv and the destination folder to take the 'foo' you provide when you run the script.

Comment: Workaround: `alias myrm='mv -t /home/user/Trash'`

Comment: @Cyrus It's not a workaround, it's *the right way*.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus and others for comments. The alias myrm='mv -t /home/user/Trash/} solved the problem.

Comment: Moving to ~/Trash won't allow you to recover the file using the desktop applications. See @deshmukh's solution for How To Not Reinvent The Wheel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, you don’t use `$` when you call an alias. 
`$` is for expanding a variable (and a few other things
that aren’t particularly relevant to this question).

But, secondly, aliases do *work* a little like variables,
in the sense that they (at the risk of oversimplifying a little)
just expand to a bunch of words. 
You say you want to do `myrm foo`,
but that would expand to `mv /home/user/Trash/* foo`,
which doesn’t make sense.

A simple solution would be
to define the alias to be `mv -t /home/user/Trash`,
which would work because `mv` supports the

```
mv -t destination_dir  file …
```

syntax
as an alternative to the

```
mv file … destination_dir
```

syntax.

But you can get greater flexibility with a shell function. 
These combine the flexibility of scripts with the (low) overhead of aliases. 
For example,

```
myrm() { mv "$@" /home/user/Trash; }
```

will cause `myrm foo` to be interpreted as `mv foo /home/user/Trash`.

Comment: I think the `$` is from his shell, normally all the lines in a terminal start with `$` to say it's a non-root shell

Comment: Yes, that could be what he means.

Answer (score 7):

Probably easier solution is to use `trash-cli` package. Then you can just do `alias myrm=trash` and then `trash foo` to accomplish what you want to. Except that foo will now go to `~/. local/share/Trash`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, with `mv` you have to use it like `mv source destination`.

With your alias it's vice-versa `mv destination source`.

Also you don't need the asterisk `*` at the end, because it works with the destination as a folder. Make sure your folder `/home/user/Trash` exists with `mkdir /home/user/Trash`.

To solve your alias idea, I would recommend you to have a look at this stackoverflow questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/7131670/7311363

This will lead to that solution; please add this to your `~/.bashrc` and do a `source ~/.bashrc` after adding:

```
myrm() {
 /bin/mv "$@" /home/user/Trash/
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the links, I don't like to copy other people's work

Comment: I saw this answer when it was the only one here. If it had explicit solution, I would have upvoted it right away. I hesitated but upvoted eventually because the links are useful, they give insight and stay within Stack Exchange. Main problem with link-only answers is the linked target may disappear, but I expect if these targets suddenly disappear from Internet, so will this entire question.

Comment: added the solution and left the most fitting link, the other link was https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438147/7311363 qft

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments, the `mv` syntax is different you can do :

```
myrm(){ mv "$@" $HOME/Trash/; }
```

that can handle multiple files as argument

However this simple alias does not handle file name collision, as well as metadata (from where it has been removed, ...).

For a more complete solution, you can simply use the package `trash-cli` which is pretty good and come with few tools (eg. empty files thar are in the trash for X days, ...).

Answer (score 1):

There is another useful alias you could consider if you have `gvfs-bin` package installed in your host:

```
alias myrm='gvfs-trash`
```

It moves your files to the bin. Also, the proper files are written in your $TRASH folder (such as `info/`, `files/` ...). So you don't have to worry for that. Example : Going in the bin and clicking `restore` will perfectly work.

That's redundant with `trash-cli` but your host may have only one of them already installed, so if you don't have trash-cli, give it a try.

Comment: Is this any better or worse than the `trash-cli` package? This requires installing gvfs-bin which is also not installed on my system. I had never encountered gvfs before and just read up on it a bit at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs . I'm still not sure what its raison d'être is, but that's another question.

Comment: On all the system (Ubuntu mostly) I used it was already installed, that why I proposed it; But since you're telling me it isn't mandatory, `trash-cli` may not be any better or worse. I will update my response accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
mv "$1" /home/user/Trash/
```

or

```
mv -t /home/user/Trash/
```

instead  of

```
mv /home/user/Trash/
```

[Manpage here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv)

Comment: The first one (`mv "$1" /home/user/Trash/`) won’t work in an alias (which is what the question is asking about) and is of limited value in a function (as I said in [my answer](https://superuser.com/q/1252676/354511#1252685), ``mv "$@" /home/user/Trash`` is better).  The second one (`mv -t /home/user/Trash/`) was already given in my answer and [Cyrus’s comment](https://superuser.com/q/1252676/354511#comment1840104_1252676) before that.